# hive replace forward slash/backward slash with tripple slashes

Tags: java, sql, hive, regexp-replace

I have a table that has `/` or `\` as first value and I wanted to replace it with 3 backward slashes `\\\`. Tried many ways including concatenation but nothing worked so far. Any help is appreciated.

```
create table test ( s1 string )

insert into test(s1) values ('/')
insert into test(s1) values ('ab')
insert into test(s1) values ('\\')

select s1, regexp_replace(s1, '//','\\\\\\\\\\\\\\') from test;
```

[image]

Comment: `regex_replace('[/\\]', '\\\\\\')` Of course using a backslash is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
regexp_replace(s1,'[/\\\\]', '\\\\\\\\\\\\')
```

Regex `[/\\\\]` - means slash or backslash

It will replace all occurrences of slash or backslash with 3 backslashes. If you want to match exactly string containing only slash or backslash, use anchors: `^[/\\\\]$`

Also in the regexp you can use hex code `'\\x5c'` to match backslash: `'[/\\x5c]'`

Comment: thank you so much. I have a followup question. if the first character is / or \ then i need to replace with '\\\' otherwise I need to replace '/' or '\' with an empty space. how would i do that?  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(title,1,1)='\\' THEN CONCAT(title,"\\\\") ELSE  COALESCE(REGEXP_REPLACE(title,'[\\|\\/\\\\\t]', ''),'') is not working as expected.

Comment: @NK7983 What if title already contains two or 3 backslashes(first)? Or do you need to replace all first backslashes with 3 backslashes?

Comment: @NK7983 You can use nested regexp_replace. First replace all slashes and backslashes which are not in the beginning, then replace slash or backslash at the beginning: `regexp_replace(regexp_replace(title,'(?!^)([/\\\\]+)', ''),'^[/\\\\]+', '\\\\\\\\\\\\')`

Comment: thank you. I just used this and sent file to my vendor. I will let you know.

Comment: @NK7983 Please ask new question next time rather than asking in comments, someone else from the community may help faster